# pyqt5 layout issue after inherit from parent

Tags: python, inheritance, layout, pyqt5

I created a class 'commonlessonItem' that is parent class
after creation of parent , I have inherited it by a child class 'commonlessonpiskelStepItem'
and I added a widget to the layout
after runing program, i got this issue.

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to CommonLessonPiskelStepItem "", which already has a layout
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on CommonLessonPiskelStepItem "", which already has a layout
```

what is problem in here?
Here comes my code

```
class CommonLessonItem(MyFrame):

    def __init__(self,parent):

        super(CommonLessonItem,self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.lbl_title = CommonHeaderLabel(self)
        self.lbl_description = CommonDescriptionLabel(self)
        self.lbl_icon = CommonHeaderIcon(self)
        self.initUI()
        self.isChild = False

    def initUI(self):
        
        #set layout
        self.layout = MyGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_title,0,0,1,19)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_icon,0,19,1,1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl_description,1,0,1,20)
        
        #initialize info
        self.setInfo("Title","Description",None)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


    def setInfo(self,title,description,iconPath):
        self.lbl_title.setText(title)
        self.lbl_description.setText(description)
        if(iconPath is not None):
            self.lbl_icon.setPixmap(QPixmap(iconPath))

class CommonLessonPiskelStepItem(CommonLessonItem):
    def __init__(self,parent):
    
        super(CommonLessonPiskelStepItem,self).__init__(parent)
        # self.lbl_referUrl = CommonDescriptionLabel('wwww.piskelapp.com')
        self.initUI()
        self.lbl_icon.setPixmap(QPixmap('icons/lookstep'))
    
    def initUI(self):
        super().initUI()
        pass
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = CommonLessonPiskelStepItem(None)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you're trying to set the layout more than once.

- the first time when you create the layout: `self.layout = MyGridLayout(self)` (using the self argument results in automatically setting the layout for the widget)
- the second time when you try to set the layout: `self.setLayout(self.layout)`; the layout is already set;
- the third time when you call the `super().initUI()`: it was already and implicitly called when you used `super().__init__`;

While the second point is not an issue (if you use `setLayout` with the same layout, it will just be ignored), the third is the one causing the error, because you're trying to create a new layout for a widget that already has one, and later you also try to set that new layout for the widget.

Just remove the `super().initUI()` from the `initUI` method of the subclass.